# Data persisting in session object of hibernate after the request is processed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, soap

I have recently started working on a project with SOAP webservices, Spring and Hibernate.

I am facing the following issue:

We use SOAP UI to send requests to test our code. I have written a service which processes bills. Basically there are 2 services, one creates a bill and the other processes that bill.

We have a table called `BillTb`. Before processing a bill, we check the status of the bill. If the bill status is 3(pending), we process it. If it is not equal to 3, we do not process it. Once the bill is processed, we change the status to 4(processed).

Now if the bill status is 3, we do a number of entries in other tables and at last, status is changed to 4.

If in between processing, if the processing fails, we need to revert all those entries. So we call these entries within a transaction.

The DAO layer with hibernate code is as follows:

```
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
    import javax.persistence.Query;

        @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
            private EntityManager entityManager;

        public class BillDAOImpl implements BillDao {

        ...
        ...
        ...

        int pendingStatus = 3;
        int processedStatus = 4;

        Session session = null;

        for(int id: ids){

           Bill bill = null;


        try{
          session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

          bill= entityManager.find(Bill.class, id);

           session.getTransaction().begin();

          if(bill.status() != pendingStatus ){
             System.out.println("The bill is already processed");
        continue;
          }
        ...
...
bill.setStatus(processedStatus);
entityManager.persist(bill);

          session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch(Exception e){

        }

        }




        }
```

Now the problem is, once a bill status is changed from 3 to 4, if I change the status again to 3 by firing an update query in database, it should again work, but somehow, it reads the status as 4 only.

If I bring down the server, then execute the request again then it works for same entry.

The other transaction related parameters are set as :

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
```

Also,

```
<bean id="projectEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
        p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit" p:loadTimeWeaver-ref="loadTimeWeaver"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter" p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"
        p:dataSource-ref="datasourceBean">
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">false</prop>
                ...
                ...             
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So here it seems that session is somehow storing the bill object and when I update the bill object directly in database, it stores stale data. So what should be done to in this case. Should I clear the session at end of method?

Comment: where does that status change occur? Try to add the impl

Comment: I have updated the code. The status is updated before transaction is committed.

Comment: Why are you messing around with both an `Entitymanager` and `Session`... Your re starting session on a different object. I strongly suggest to cleanup your code (use the `EntityManager` and don't unwrap it to a `Session`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform the query inside of the transaction and also remember to commit the transaction everytime (if you trigger continue, that is ommited).

Actually i would write it like this:

```
    for(int id: ids){

        Bill bill = null;

        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        try{          
          bill= entityManager.find(Bill.class, id);

          if(bill.status() != pendingStatus ){
             System.out.println("The bill is already processed");
             tx.commit();
             continue;
          }

          bill.setStatus(processedStatus);
          entityManager.persist(bill);   

          session.flush();
          tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
          tx.rollback();
          throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Only one last question, if I put it in finally, it will always try to commit the transaction. If there is an exception, it will go to Catch block and there will be rollback. so I cannot commit in finally.. So any solution for that.

Comment: Here there are 2 try blocks and one is not having any finally or catch block. I think it will give compilation error. I tried many combinations but not able to figure out where to flush the session. The above one will not work because if there is one bill which is successfully processed and other one fails, it will rollback both the bill objects since transaction is committing outside.

Comment: ok if you want to commit after each iteration then i have upated the answer a bit